# Finding the transfer function of a common base BJT transistor amplifier

Tags: transistors, bjt, transfer-function, common-base

I've been tasked with finding the transfer function for this common base BJT amplifier in low and high frequency but I actually have no idea how to even approach it. Any help will be hugely appreciated! The component values are:

- R_Signal = 10k,
- R_B = 340k,
- R_C = 10k,
- R_L = 10k,
- C_c1 =  10uF,
- C_c2 = 10uF,
- C_E = 10uF,
- R_E = 6k,
- V_CC = 5V,
- V_EE = -5V.

For the internal capacitors, the values should be the ones given on the datasheet of an 2N3904 transistor.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Roberto, It's good you are asking for help. But can you put your finger on why you have been asked to do something for which you have no ideas about how to proceed? Is the educational situation that poorly designed? Or is there something else? Perhaps the first thing would be to describe to us what is meant by "transfer function" in this case? Could you attempt a definition for that? Does it include the source impedance? Does it include the load impedance? How would you define it? And also, have you any comfort at all with a small-signal hybrid-\$\pi\$ model?

Comment: This looks very much like a homework/exam question, and we don't give out answers to those. We will expect you to put forth a significant effort to solve this yourself, and show us all of your work. Then you can ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a conflict in your question. the schematic has no R_b or R_e but has a Current Sink.

Let’s assume it is in the linear current range.

since re=26/Ic, is small compared to R_sig, that can be ignored.

Thus Av=(R_c//R_l) / R_e for R_l<=R_c so it does not starve the collector of DC current the …

Av=0.50 = Vo/V_sig